# Italian school of algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-history

Could you please give me some pieces of information or references about the most important mathematicians (and their discoveries) in the Italian school of algebraic geometry? Is Italy still a good nation if someone want to do research in algebraic geometry?

Comment: For history, see [Italian school of algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_school_of_algebraic_geometry).

Comment: See laso Angelo Guerraggio & Pietro Nastasi, [Italian Mathematics Between the Two World Wars](https://books.google.it/books?id=S5fpiWCghYoC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2010).

Comment: "Is Italy still a good nation if someone want to do research in algebraic geometry?" - I don't think questions like this are helpful/useful. Partly because this sort of question implies that the government/country dictates the research, rather than the researchers. A better question might be "does Italy still have any world-class algebraic geometers?".

Comment: Yes you are right... I was asking if in some way, some universities have well-known research groups specialized in it.

Comment: @user502940 Roma ("La Sapienza" and "Tor Vergata" Universities; about "Roma 2" I do not know); Pisa (University and "Scuola Superiore Universitaria Normale"); Bologna(?); Parma(?); Milano (surely "Statale" University); Padova; Trieste (S.I.S.S.A., I.C.T.P., University of Trieste).